# unable to live stream using srt, facing "Unsupported timestamp reference clock" issue

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, h.265, rtsp-client

I am trying to stream video using the SRT protocol, streaming source is a rtsp client.

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=3 rtspsrc location="rtsp://admin:admin@localhost/live.sdp" short-header=TRUE name=demux demux. ! rtph265depay ! queue ! video/x-h265 ! mpegtsmux name=mux1 ! srtsink uri=srt://:8888 demux. ! queue ! rtpmp4adepay ! aacparse ! mux1.
```

When I try to run above pipeline, I get `FIXME` logs and I am not able to see the stream on VLC player.

Logs:

```
0:00:00.285731958  2338   0x7f600338f0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<fakesrc0:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
0:00:00.294357875  2338   0x7f600338a0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<fakesrc1:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:00.349911500  2338   0x7f60033400 FIXME        rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:1551:gst_jitter_buffer_sink_parse_caps:<rtpjitterbuffer0> Unsupported timestamp reference clock
0:00:00.350078166  2338   0x7f60033400 FIXME        rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:1559:gst_jitter_buffer_sink_parse_caps:<rtpjitterbuffer0> Unsupported media clock
0:00:00.355827125  2338   0x7f600334a0 FIXME        rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:1551:gst_jitter_buffer_sink_parse_caps:<rtpjitterbuffer1> Unsupported timestamp reference clock
0:00:00.358561833  2338   0x7f600334a0 FIXME        rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:1559:gst_jitter_buffer_sink_parse_caps:<rtpjitterbuffer1> Unsupported media clock
0:00:02.358866251  2338   0x7f50002400 FIXME           rtph265depay gstrtph265depay.c:1310:gst_rtp_h265_depay_process:<rtph265depay0> Assuming DONL field is not present
0:00:02.360083834  2338   0x7f50002400 FIXME           rtph265depay gstrtph265depay.c:1310:gst_rtp_h265_depay_process:<rtph265depay0> Assuming DONL field is not present
0:00:02.360472292  2338   0x7f50002400 FIXME           rtph265depay gstrtph265depay.c:1310:gst_rtp_h265_depay_process:<rtph265depay0> Assuming DONL field is not present
0:00:02.360655334  2338   0x7f50002400 FIXME           rtph265depay gstrtph265depay.c:1310:gst_rtp_h265_depay_process:<rtph265depay0> Assuming DONL field is not present
0:00:02.360766126  2338   0x7f50002400 FIXME           rtph265depay gstrtph265depay.c:1310:gst_rtp_h265_depay_process:<rtph265depay0> Assuming DONL field is not present
0:00:02.360916376  2338   0x7f50002400 FIXME           rtph265depay gstrtph265depay.c:1310:gst_rtp_h265_depay_process:<rtph265depay0> Assuming DONL field is not present
0:00:02.361559709  2338     0x36f5acf0 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3248:gst_base_sink_default_event:<srtsink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
0:00:02.362658667  2338   0x7f50002400 FIXME           rtph265depay gstrtph265depay.c:1310:gst_rtp_h265_depay_process:<rtph265depay0> Assuming DONL field is not present
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the videorate gstreamer element before the srtsink element.
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videorate/index.html?gi-language=c

Comment: getting linking error after putting videorate element.